# For $Z = X-Y$ with $X,Y$ independent and equal probability distributions, does $p_Z$ always achieve maximum at zero?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $Z = X-Y$, $X,Y$ are independent, and $p_X = p_Y$. Then $\text{argmax} p_Z(z) = 0$ always?

For $p_Z$, I get
$$
p_Z(z) = \int p_X(x)p_X(x-z) dx
$$
and stuck at here.

Or would there be a counterexample?

In the case the above is not true in general, what if we assume $p_X$ is symmetric about a point?

Comment: Hint: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: How about this case，if X and Y are independent and N(0,1) distributed.

Comment: @Did Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @JGWang Yeah, how about it... Sorry but what is the point of your comment exactly?

Comment: @Did Thank you, you are right, I was confused by the "argmax".